# Best source for learning cloud based website and web app development

Tags: web-applications, web, cloud

I'm interested in building a cloud based website as well as cloud web applications. I need a source where I can learn how to build.

Answer (score 0):

You can read such concepts in any of the Web Development books available. Here are some links you might want to have a look to get a feel.
http://cocoon.apache.org/2.1/tutorial/tutorial-develop-webapp.html

You might also want to have a look at some projects
http://freecode.com/tags/web-application-development

Answer (score 0):

I just discover this [book](http://www.packtpub.com/cloud-development-and-deployment-with-cloudbees/book) about Cloud Development and Deployment on a PaaS. It will show you how to deploy and how to build on the cloud. This book is specific of a PaaS provider, but you can learn how the cloud works in general terms as most of the PaaS providers work in a similar way. For example, you will see that on a multi-tenant environment, the file storage system is not persistent.

On the cloud you have several concepts: IaaS, PaaS and SaaS. So you should choose the one which meets your needs. You have more information about them on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing#Service_models).

Basically, on an IaaS you have to manage all the installation and configuration process of the web container, database,.., when on a PaaS you just need to concentrate your efforts on the development process without taking care of anything more. So just deploy or enable the services that you want.